# Why is (European) money in units of $1,2,5,10,20,50, \cdots\;$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

In the old days, in the Netherlands, we had 1 ct (cent), 5 ct (stuiver),
10 ct (dubbeltje), 25 ct (kwartje), 1 gld (gulden), 2.5 gld (rijksdaalder),
10 gld (tientje), ... 
 And then they decided we should pay in Euros for the
rest of our lives.
A picture says more than a thousand words:

[image]

Yes, everybody knows that it's practical. But why this particular choice?

What's wrong with the old coins sequence? What's good with the $1,2,5,10,20,50, \cdots\;$ sequence?

EDIT. Gathered some evidence that the question as stated *is indeed mathematical* :

- [Postage stamp problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postage_stamp_problem) (Wikipedia)
- [Coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) (Wikipedia)
- [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) (Wikipedia)
- [Preferred number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-2-5_series#1-2-5_series) (Wikipedia)

Maybe those references form already an answer to the question.

Comment: Is this a mathematics question?

Comment: I _guess_ its a general convention,followed across the world. For eg. in India (my country) we also have Re.1,Rs.2,5,10,20,50,100 currency notes,though Rs. 1 and 2 notes are not so much used these days and are replaced by coins.

Comment: @Sid Another Indian Sid that enjoys math!  And here I was thinking I was the only one!

Comment: @han Je had natuurlijk ook nog de daalder. Maar toegegeven, dat was ver voor onze tijd (in 1847 afgeschaft). http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daalder

Comment: @Sid Now I see that you could choose 1,7,9 and 43 for the general convention equally well. Thanks for mathematical background.

Comment: @JiK: some people seems to think so: http://graal.ens-lyon.fr/~yrobert/algo/coins1.pdf (paper "Why this country needs a 18c piece?" by Shallit)

Comment: I can'T respond as it is on hold, but it is mainly because 2 and 5 are relatively prime and this helps to use less coins for the same price.

Comment: @Val, Are you not increasing the complexity of money counting if you choose 1,7,9 and 43 for your denominations. You see, people struggle with multiple of 7,9 and with 43! dear lord...they will kill themselves. The idea is to break any number in the easily countable denominations.

Comment: @sid I am trolling Sid's answer `it is a matter of convention`. I do not like answers that answer nothing and troll them. You see, once I have exposed its stupidity, you have managed to come up with a better explanation ;)

Comment: @Val, i think he(the other Sid) deleted his comment and thus the confusion. (-;

Comment: @Sid Yes, you may look at the deleted message, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883522/why-is-european-money-in-units-of-1-2-5-10-20-50-cdots?noredirect=1#comment1823419_883522 . He even cannot delete when deletes something.

Comment: OK, I might have expected anything, but not that the question would be non-mathematical. I cannot imagine that there is no sort of mathematical reason for the sequence

Comment: You want the same coins/notes in all Euro countries, so some had to change. Doesn't mean there was something particularly wrong. Assuming you want 0.01, 0.10, 1, 10, and 100, question is what you put in the gaps. Since everything is decimal, you'd want powers of 2 and 5. I suppose 2 and 5 is most easy to calculate; 2.5 and 5 a bit harder. 4 would be unusual. 3, 6, 7, 8, 9 would be weird.

Comment: I recommend that you read the “preferred number” article in Wikipedia; I think it is most relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated by Darth Geek, $1$, $2$, and $5$ are the proper divisors of $10$.  This means that all sufficiently large powers of $10$ are achievable by using a finite number of *any* chosen coin/note.  Mental math is also really easy (one $10$, two $5$'s, five $2$'s, etc...).

Additionally, these numbers form an approximate geometric sequence.  If you are a retail store manager and want to (approximately) double the price of every good, simply choose the next largest coin/note size.  For example, a $5$ coin item would now cost $10$ coins, while a $10$ coin item would be $20$.

Here are some related resources:

- [Preferred Numbers](http://sizes.com/numbers/preferred_numbers.htm)
- [1-2-5 Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number#1-2-5_series)
- [E Series](http://www.logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html)

Comment: The answer to the question is more mundane than I anticipated but so be it.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a mix between two facts:

1.- If Alice wants to buy something from Bob and both Alice and Bob have each one of every coin  and note, it is guaranteed that Alice can buy that something regardless of the price (all numbers can be constructed with the money from Alice and the change that Bob can give her). The simplest way to do this would be to use powers of three for the currency. This is where the second fact comes in.

2.- We use the decimal system and 1,2,5 are the divisors of 10. So it makes it easier to compute what selections of coins and notes to use to pay for goods and serices.